# How to get conditional in TPL working with bound value

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I've got code as below where I want to hide a row if the bound value is false.  It seems that the template is always evalulating as false. I've tried with and w/o curly braces.  If I change it to 0 == 0 then it works.

```
  {
        height: 185,
        xtype: 'panel',
        tpl: [
            '<table>',
            '    <tpl if="{sessionPrepMaterialsUrlExists} == 0">',
                '    <tr>',
                '        <td  width="250">',
                '             <a href="{sessionPrepMaterialsUrl}" target="_blank" >Materials Prep Download Link</a>',
                '        </td>',
                '    </tr>',
            '    </tpl>',


            '    </table>'
        ],
        bind: {
            data: {

                sessionsMaterialUrl: '{selectedSession.sessionsMaterialUrl}',
                sessionPrepMaterialsUrl: '{selectedSession.sessionPrepMaterialsUrl}',
                sessionsMaterialUrlExists: '{selectedSession.sessionsMaterialUrlExists}',
                sessionPrepMaterialsUrlExists: '{selectedSession.sessionPrepMaterialsUrlExists}'
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: I believe the bind here is a bad solution, while tpl is used on creation time and binding happens with delay, so you will never have a proper value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try:

```
<tpl if="!sessionPrepMaterialsUrlExists">
```

Or:

```
<tpl if="sessionPrepMaterialsUrlExists == 0">
```